# how to setState to false after run a Modal, and go to other Modal?

Tags: reactjs

I want to go to modal 2 from `modal1`.

I click button, with `onclick={this.openprofile}` and setstate of show open profile to `true`.

Then I want to `setState` of current modal (`modal1`) to `false`, but I can not?

I use from `componentdidmount()`,... and other lifecycle methods but can not set it to `false`.

```
export default class Register_Modal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showBaseModal: true,
            codemodal: false
        };
        this.openCodeModal = this.openCodeModal.bind(this);
        this.closeCodeModal = this.closeCodeModal.bind(this);
    }
    openCodeModal(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            codemodal: true,
            showBaseModal: false
        });
    }
    closeCodeModal() {
        this.setState({ codemodal: false });
    }
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.showBaseModal && (
                    <Modal
                        isOpen={this.props.open}
                        onRequestClose={this.props.close}
                        ariaHideApp={false}
                        contentLabel="selected option"
                        isClose={this.props.close}
                        style={customStyles}
                        onClick={this.props.close}

                    >

                        <h2>hhhh</h2>
                        <button onClick={this.props.close} >انصراف</button>
                        <button onClick={this.openCodeModal} >بعدی</button>

                    </Modal>
                )}


                {this.state.codemodal && (
                    <div >
                        <RegisterCode_Modal open={() => true} close={this.closeCodeModal} />

                    </div>
                ) }

            </div>

        );

    }

}
```

in these code, when I click button to setState codemodal, I go to other modal, but I can not change current state of codemodal and showBase modal to initial value.

Comment: You can manage the state in parent component which hosts these modal components. I would create separate react component which will have modal component code and then from parent component you will change the state to trigger behavior.

Comment: Please paste the code where you are doing that. From text we can only guess.

Comment: I want to know: How I use setState to change value of my state, WITHOUT click on button?